# Convert Loop problem Recursive Solution in Scala

Tags: scala, recursion, while-loop, tail-recursion

I've written the following method `inshuffle` (working perfectly fine) which takes a list and returns the count of step for [in-shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_shuffle). It uses two methods `splitLists` and `shuffle` which i've already written and will provide the implementation. I wanted to remove the loop and wanted to try some recursive solution. I need some help in this regard. Any help will be much appreciated. thanks
Here is the implementation of `splitLists(ls, n)`

```
def splitLists(list: List[Any], n: Int) = {
    if (n > list.length) {
      throw new Exception("N is greater than length of list")
    }
    else if (n == list.length) {
      List(list, List())
    }
    else {
      List(list.slice(0, n),
        list.slice(n, list.length))
    }
  }
```

And here is the code for `shuffle` method:

```
def shuffle(list1: List[Any], list2: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
    list1.zipAll(list2, "", "")
      .flatMap(_.productIterator.toList)
      .filter(_ != "")
  }
```

Here is the `**InShuffle**` method that I want to convert loop-based solution to a recursion based solution.

```
  def inshuffle(list1:List[Any]): Int ={
    var count = 1
    var list:List[Any] = list1
    val list_copy = list1

    var list_of_lists = splitLists(list, list.length/2)
    list = shuffle(list_of_lists(0), list_of_lists(1))

    while(!list.equals(list_copy)){
      list_of_lists = splitLists(list, list.length/2)
      list = shuffle(list_of_lists(0), list_of_lists(1))
      count += 1
    }
  count
  }
```

**Explanation** 
If i pass a list `[1,2,3,4]` Following interations are of `while` loop

Input Passed = `[1,2,3,4]` 
`Iteration 1:` `SplitLists` returns `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and then this list of lists is passed to shuffle which return `[1,3,2,4]` (Alternative shuffle of lists)

Input Passed = `[1,3,2,4]` 
`Iteration 2:` `SplitLists` returns `[[1,3],[2,4]]` and then this list of lists is passed to shuffle which return `[1,2,3,4]` (Alternative shuffle of lists)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `var` if possible.

I could come up with the following recursive solution.
Please correct me if I understood it in the wrong way.

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
  def inShuffleRec(list: List[Any], count: Int = 1): Int = {
    val (left, right) = list.splitAt(list.size/2)
    val shuffled = shuffle(left, right)

    if (list.equals(shuffled))
      count
    else
      inShuffleRec(shuffled, count + 1)
  }
```

NOTE: Your solution goes into an infinite loop for the input list having empty string in it. For an e.g. try running it with input `List("", 1, 2.0)`